# Is it possible that a satellite once was a small planet?

Tags: astronomy, astrophysics

Very common fact that a planet has satellite which  revolves around it and has an impact  on that planet too.Is it possible that a small planet had been bombarded with a big planet and transformed into a small mass body know as a satellite?

Comment: Yes. In the early Solar System, there were lots of collisions.

Answer (score 1):

In the early days of the solar system, it is generally believed , as the comment above implies, that it was a place of constant collisions.

The moon may have been part of the Earth, there is strong evidence for that, and an impact is  the most probable way that it would be have been able to became a separate orbiting body.

For the giant planets, Jupiter etc, their gravity was enough to capture passing small bodies and create satellite systems from them.

Another way to reduce to large planet to a satellite occur by what's called the Roche limit, whereby the gravity of the larger body exerts a large differential  gravitational force on a smaller orbiting planet and reduces it to smaller pieces, as the Earth would do to the Moon if it got too close.

Having only our own solar system limits the data we can gather and the theories we can test. By using space probes  such as Kepler, we get a chance to study other solar systems and establish a pattern of planetary and satellite formation.

Comment: how do these planets, satellites become so nicely spherical even after a nasty collision?

Comment: By gravity. Planets are roughly spherical because beyond a certain size, the gravitational force is too great for large deviations from the spherical form to hold themselves up. An easily accessible example is a sand castle; it's hard to build a large sand castle because the weight of the sand overcomes the adhesion of the grains.

Comment: @user31748 also, when the components of a satellite or planet crash together, the kinetic energy is so high that the rock melts, and turns to liquid, so it's "easier" for gravity to work it into a round, or roughly round shape, that it would be if it was solid.